# What the f*** just happened?

Tags: discussion

I just logged on and found that, no doubt for my convenience,
everything on the ELU page was now in a different place.

I'm sure that someone would like to take responsibility for this putative improvement.
If so, do you spose they could give us a conversion table for finding the stuff we're used to?
Or do we have to endure someone's idea of a "tour"?

> **Postscript**:
>   I have just been notified that this question has been awarded the `Nice Question` badge. 
>   In honor of this token of automatic esteem, I've restored the original title,
>   since it's now, officially, `Nice`.
>
> **Post-postscript**:
>   Andrew Leach points out that
>   "The question might be nice, but most of the upvotes were for the edited title."
>
> Of course, ***I*** didn't say "What the f***?"
>   It's **impossible** to say "What the f***?"
>   It's putting asterisks in my mouth and I don't like it.
>
> But I leave it to the readers. Before once again restoring my original title, I pause and
>   leave the topic open for discussion here. It's basically just another user interface issue.
>   And the tag that I was forced to choose for this question says "discussion", anyway.

Comment: For starts, how do I get the hell out of "Meta" and go to "Main" without restarting?

Comment: Yeah, I was planning to click from here to "main" to see what you mean ... and I see what you mean.

Comment: I found the main site under the StackExchange pulldown on the topbar.

Comment: I was irritated that I couldn't click through to chat after wading through the flag queue. Otherwise I like the changes.

Comment: And you can switch between Meta and Main using the old multicollider, which is now a useful-ish site switching tool.

Comment: ... somewhere on the page, no doubt. Reachable by going through a "tour" video.

Comment: I see no one has taken responsibility yet. Isn't this what we have Elders for? Or is it a matter of having to toe the Party Line?

Comment: One thing which is definitely missing is the highlighted number for the Review queue. I just clicked it and found an edit waiting.

Comment: @KitFox - What is the "old multicollider"? Side note: I can't believe John Lawler dropped an F-bomb. At least it was only in meta :^)

Comment: BTW, note latest edit above. The question is open.

Comment: There's a site policy to keep profanity out of titles. Everywhere else, it's fair game, but question titles can show up in the oddest places, so they're best kept family-friendly. (The "nice question" badge is purely based on the number of upvotes.)

Comment: @Marthaª: (That's what I meant by "automatic esteem".) I think the badges are silly, but what's sillier is somebody deciding what's "profane". So far we've only heard from two people, you and Andrew, both representing Authority, but nothing from users. Do users care? Does it matter what they care? Tune in again tomorrow for the latest installment.

Comment: I represent Authority? When did that happen? How do I undo it? :)

Comment: I'm not Authority; Authority is Diamond-bearing. I'm a User.

Comment: I wouldn't know; all I know is that some people represent it as a rule and try to enforce it. Is that Authority? Who changed the interface? Is that Authority? I see that there are now 3 more votes. What are they votes for?

Comment: Am I missing something here? There’s a new header (which I’m guessing is SE-wide), but apart from that, nothing at all seems to have changed for me. At least nothing that I’d ever noticed before.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Diamond-bearing isn't really authority either.  Certainly most diamond-bearers had little or no influence on the design of the top bar...

Comment: @snailboat That depends; there are your regular run-of-the-mill *locadiamonds* like KitFox♦ and RegDwigнt♦, and then there are the *ubidiamonds* (ᴀᴋᴀ *semperdiamonds*) like Shog9♦♦♦ and Anna Lear♦♦♦. It’s those latter whose feet you’ll need to hold to the fire on this one.

Comment: See the [MSO post on ‘Is anyone else personally terrified of the new bar at the top?’](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209957).

Comment: You'll soon find your way around the new top bar design, and it won't seem such an issue. It's O.K. I just think the jet black looks horrible with the antique pink theme. Against grey, it's less annoying.

Comment: I've had time to get used to it, and it still seems like a major step down in usability.  I want my main/meta toggle back, and I want the chat link back, too.

Comment: I **told** you that innovations arise in the written language, too. Rail as you like against the prescriptivists (the real ones, not the 18th-century strawmen), you cannot suppress those who control the means of production.

Comment: Some people do indeed say "f***", generally pronounced /ɛf.ʃtaːɐ̯.ʃtaːɐ̯.ʃtaːɐ̯/ though in the film *In The Loop* it is at one point pronounced /ɛf.ʃtaːɐ̯.ʃtaːɐ̯.kʌnt/.

Comment: When I go for a walk at night, and I look up and look at the stars, all I can see now is "uck uck uck"

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Well, there's an obsolete comment if I've ever seen one ;)

Answer (score 17):

If you want you can blame me, It won't do any good, but I read about it in the [blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/?cb=1) and said nothing.

Comment: OK, it's all your fault then. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The consensus appears to be that the new title bar is

1. illegible
2. ugly

These are, it appears, negligible concerns, outweighed by a parsimonious reluctance to consult a Real Designer about decisions which The Programmers are perfectly capable of botching on their own. These are, after all, the same people who compose and decompose the *Help* pages and other informational matter without consulting an Actual Writer.

What vexes me is the lack of notice. A couple of weeks ago the admirable [Laura](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11199/laura) took the trouble to announce, [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4277/24489) and on [ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/857/32), that these sites were specifically excluded from a new policy which might have occasioned distress and misunderstanding. Why was the same trouble not taken to announce a new design which *does* affect us all? Why could this not have been announced on each site’s meta, instead of being relegated to the Community Bulletin? —which I’m sure many users besides me (and Prof. Lawler) never notice.

Comment: Who moved my cheese?

Answer (score 4):

The new top bar is a network-wide feature, so it wasn't announced before anywhere but on the [main Stack Exchange meta site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

There have been [many complaints about the new top bar on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/top-bar). Most of the complaints are being dismissed as fear of the new. Neither usability nor design are perceived as legitimate reasons for complaints.

If you're feeling lost, refer to **[New top bar quick reference guide / Where has the link to  gone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210186/new-top-bar-quick-reference-guide-where-has-the-link-to-x-gone/210187#210187)**

Answer (score 1):

This is being discussed/debated extensively on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). 
My take on it
is at [Complaints about new interface design](https://meta.superuser.com/q/7429/150988);
I’ve asked to have it moved (from [Meta Super User](http://meta.superuser.com))
to Meta Stack Overflow, but apparently that’s not a priority for the moderators.

Comment: Probly time to get the League of Super Users involved, then. We may need superpowers to combat our new interface overlords.

Comment: “[We have met the enemy and he is us.](http://www.igopogo.com/we_have_met.htm)”?