# Introducing the "custom filter"

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, hidden-features

Do you remember back in the day when you could navigate easily between pages showing *newest*, *featured*, *frequent*, *votes*, *active*, and *unanswered* questions?

ca. 2017

[image]

### Introducing [Custom Filters](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/25/introducing-custom-filters/?cb=1)

With the arrival of the new *custom filter* feature on July 25 2019, two of those buttons are now hidden from view.

[image]

The *featured* button is named *bounties* on this page and the buttons *frequent* and *votes* have vanished.

**Click on the “more” button**

[image]

I think it is a great shame that the page showing the most upvoted questions is now shoved away. New visitors will not easily find this button, and I suspect they will lose interest in EL&U sooner rather than later. On a personal level, I fell in love with EL&U when I began visiting the most upvoted questions. I remember voting on these “old” questions and answers  and thinking I had found something really special and useful for me. Nowadays not so much...

Can we ask the developers to make the *votes* button appear on the *All Questions* page as it did two years ago?

Does anyone else find the hidden *votes* button to be more harmful than helpful to the site's health?

I feel that EL&U is falling on the sidelines, its losing users, apathy is rife and it has no voice on Meta (or maybe it never did) that champions its cause.

What are *your* opinions about the custom filter? How useful is it for *us*?

Comment: It is never  wise to criticize the changes of the layout of SE pages. We’ve gone through that before. Having said that I don’t find the “filter” option so appalling and user unfriendly. As for new users, since they start from scratch, they’ll naturally  click on every “key” and learn how to use the site.

Comment: @user067531 how useful is the filter button for us? For ELLers? The filter does not improve my experience, it adds another function/feature which EL&U did not ask for.

Comment: I don’t think ELU users have any say in the design and layout of the site. However much we complain. It is not our job. https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10885/elus-top-bar-stopped-being-elegant-in-2013

Comment: @Mari-LouA I agree with you. They took away a default “sort by votes” option on the app a long time ago, you have to set it up manually for every site, and it’s endlessly frustrating. If I had to speculate, SE wants to avoid a “the rich get richer and the poor stay poor” problem.